# Task not Cancelling as expected

Tags: c#, task, cancellation-token

We got the following scenario:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // trigger the delayed function
        trigger();

        // cancel the running task.
        _token.Cancel();

        // keep window open ;-)
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static CancellationTokenSource _token = null;
    private static async void trigger()
    {
        _token = new CancellationTokenSource();

        try
        {
            // run task
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                // wait time
                await Task.Delay(2500);

                // we should be cancelled here !!
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IsCancellationRequested={0}", _token.Token.IsCancellationRequested));
                Console.WriteLine("SHOULD NOT HAPPEN");

            }, _token.Token);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

IMO the expected behaviour is that the operation of the task is cancelled mostly after  the *Task.Delay(2500)* is processed.

But the console is printing:

```
IsCancellationRequested=True
SHOULD NOT HAPPEN
```

This just feels like a bug. If you add the *CancellationToken* as parameter to the *Task.Delay*-Function it will work as expected.

So how to handle a cancellation if a function inside the task uses *Task.Delay*, that you may not know?

Comment: [You keep using that `CancellationToken` there. I do not think it means what you think it means.](https://twitter.com/aSteveCleary/status/572759402391969793)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cancellation in .Net is cooperative. Passing a token as parameter to `Task.Run` only associates the token with the returned task.

To actually cancel the task you need to check the token inside the task itself. If you want the task to be canceled while inside the delay you'll need to pass the token to the `Task.Delay` method. Otherwise you can only check while before or after the delay:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{
    _token.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    await Task.Delay(2500, _token.Token);
    _token.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IsCancellationRequested={0}", _token.Token.IsCancellationRequested));
    Console.WriteLine("SHOULD NOT HAPPEN");

}, _token.Token);
```

Comment: Additionally you shouldn't access the `CancellationTokenSource` in the Task anyway but the Token itself. Look at the 
[MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: But if i pass the token in Task.Delay it will generate an exception witch will cause loss of performance, i am right?

Comment: For me it is also not clear enough why i can pass the Token through Task.Run as second parameter. It seems senseless for me.

Comment: @ElMarchewko You pass the token for 2 reasons: 1. If the token was canceled before the task even started then it would be canceled preemptively before starting. 2. When you call `ThrowIfCancelltionRequested` it only throws an `OperationCanceledException` and the returned task is marked as *"faulted"*. If you pass a `CancellationToken` to `Task.Run` then it checks if the the `OperationCanceledException.CancellationToken` matches the one that was passed and only then is the task considered *"canceled"*.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nice MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607(v=vs.110).aspx

> The calling thread does not forcibly end the task; it only signals
>   that cancellation is requested. If the task is already running, it is
>   up to the user delegate to notice the request and respond
>   appropriately. If cancellation is requested before the task runs, then
>   the user delegate is never executed and the task object transitions
>   into the Canceled state.

As i3arnon suggested you can check the state and throw an exception before carrying out the actual work. Code excerpt from the article:

```
...
  // Was cancellation already requested?  
      if (ct.IsCancellationRequested == true) {
         Console.WriteLine("Task {0} was cancelled before it got started.",
                           taskNum);
         ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
      } 
...
```